# Change list background color in Pharo with Spec

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo, spec-ui

Is this supposed to change a list background color to red in Pharo?

```
ListModel new 
    items: (1 to: 10);
    color: Color red;
    openWithSpec.
```

Because it's always white no matter what, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicolai Hess proposed this workaround [on the Pharo Dev list](http://forum.world.st/Change-list-background-color-in-Pharo-with-Spec-tp4760977p4760981.html):

```
ListModel new 
    items: (1 to: 10);
    backgroundColorBlock: [ :item :index |Color red ];
    openWithSpec.
```

Answer (score 4):

That's actually a Morphic issue.

It needs a massive refactoring to allow this feature,
so sadly it's not planned for anytime soon.

Sorry
Benjamin Van Ryseghem